# docker-compose syncing folders : how to trigger the sync after build?

Tags: docker, storybook

Im trying to run a storybook container for react.

Storybook is making new files in app/frontend/src/stories in the build process.

I would like to add the files I have in my /frontend/src/stories folder and modify these files and i would like first add the files and then the modifications to take effect in the container app/frontend/src/stories folder.

How can i do that ?

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
  nginx_storybook:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/storybook/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
      - /app/frontend/node_modules
      - ./frontend/src/components:/app/frontend/src/components
      - ./frontend/src/stories:/app/frontend/src/stories
```

The volume configuration doesnt work : no files in my ./frontend/src/stories appear in the container /app/frontend/src/stories folder and reciprocally...
I used to do -v myfolder:containerfolder and i used to work with docker, but i dont know how to do with docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

I seems the user used in the container doesn't have enough permissions to see the files and edit them
Try adding the following line at the end of your Dockerfile

```
USER <some UID> # USER 5000
```

then in the host call the following command

```bash
sudo chown -R <the same UID> ./frontend/src/stories
```

Comment: thanks, uid is the same as $USER ? or how can i retrieve the uid otherwise?

Comment: in my answer, I proposed to use a new UID in the container and give it the permissions, but if you want to use your UID in the container (in this case, no need to call chown command), you can retrieve it by calling the command: `id`